# A map that preserves unit distances is an isometry

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, isometry

Let  $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2, \|x-y\|=1\Rightarrow \|g(x)-g(y)\|=1$. Prove that $g$ is an isometry.

I managed to prove the following: Let $A$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}_+$,   $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2, \|x-y\|\in A\Rightarrow \|g(x)-g(y)\|=\|x-y\|$. Then $g$ is an isometry. I don't see how it helps to solve the problem, though.

Comment: Without further assumptions on $g$, the claim is not true.

Comment: @IttayWeiss : thank you, do you have a counter-example?

Comment: I mis-read the condition. I need to think about this some more.

Comment: This is the 2D case of the [Beckman–Quarles theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beckman%E2%80%93Quarles_theorem). You might as well lookup the original article referenced in the wikipedia page.